# How to get Record ID URL using a text formula

Tags: formula

Without using APEX or VF, how can I get a record ID URL using a text formula?

I can do a formula to get the base URL:

```
LEFT($Api.Partner_Server_URL_260, FIND( '/services', $Api.Partner_Server_URL_260))
```

but I need the record ID included.

E.g. 
https://na23.salesforce.com/a0G16000015CZsb

Thanks in advance

Comment: If you are creating a formula field, you can get it by appending Id to your existing formula. Ex _LEFT($Api.Partner_Server_URL_260, FIND( '/services', $Api.Partner_Server_URL_260)) + Id_

Comment: You are awesome!!!